# Schedule Gaps in Python datetime

Tags: python, python-2.7, date, datetime, schedule

I'm trying to get available times from a given schedule:

```
167.0 01:50:48 02:09:56   
167.0 03:48:08 04:07:16   
167.0 05:45:25 06:04:32   
167.0 07:42:39 08:01:45   
167.0 08:49:05 22:16:43    
167.0 23:17:18 23:59:59   
168.0 03:11:24 03:32:05      
168.0 00:00:00 03:32:05   
168.0 05:08:25 05:29:16      
168.0 07:05:04 07:26:02   
168.0 09:00:53 23:09:45   
169.0 01:47:09 02:07:32   
169.0 00:00:00 02:07:32  
169.0 03:43:50 04:04:09    
169.0 05:40:42 06:00:59   
169.0 07:37:44 07:48:00   
169.0 09:34:55 23:59:59    
170.0 00:00:00 01:32:00  
170.0 10:37:37 23:59:59   
171.0 02:36:01 02:45:24   
171.0 00:00:00 02:45:24   
171.0 04:33:10 04:92:34   
171.0 06:30:21 06:89:47   
171.0 08:27:34 08:47:02   
171.0 10:24:49 23:59:59   
172.0 03:59:50 04:19:21    
172.0 00:00:00 04:19:21  
172.0 05:57:01 06:16:33   
172.0 07:54:14 08:13:48   
172.0 09:51:29 10:11:04   
172.0 11:48:44 23:59:59
```

Where the first column is the day of year, the middle column is the start time, and the right column is the end time.

Is there a way to invert this so that, for a given day of year, it shows the available times between 00:00:00 and 23:59:59?

Comment: So the data provided is the busy time?

Answer (score 0):

Well, think about a simple calendar application. You block out times that are invalid, and your calendar shows you those and the times that *are* valid. Thankfully, you're using military time, which makes the problem less complicated.

Ultimately, you'll be left with a list of times.

Here's roughly how I would go about this, given the list.

First, use `string.split()` on each line. This will give you a list, with  each entry segmented.

> Start at 00:00:00 and read until the first time slot you encounter, assuming they are in order.
>
> Add that entry in the list, from 00:00:00 to the beginning of that window.
>
> From the end of the first time block, read to the beginning of the following one. That's another interval.
>
> Rinse and repeat until you have a list of all the times from 00:00:00 to 23:59:59 that do *not* have an interval associated with them.

Does this help at all?